# How to add onClick to React MUI Fab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use Floating Action Button from MUI5: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-floating-action-button/

When I add onClick to this button, no action is being performed. My code is below

```
<Grid>
 <Fab size="small" color="success" aria-label="add" onClick={e => console.log("Fab clicked")}>
   <Typography>1ABC</Typography>
 </Fab>
</Grid>
```

When I click the button, I'm not getting anything in console. How do I add onClick function to Fab button?

Comment: I just [tested](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-smoke-92ny9m?file=/demo.tsx) the onClick prop on the Fab component and it's working as intended.

Comment: The code looks good to me. you must get the log

Comment: It was cache problem and worked after clearing cache and restarting.

Comment: You need to show your whole code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved with the label tag.

```
  <label>
    <Fab
      style={{
        color: 'blue',
        margin: 10,
      }}
      onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}
    >
      <AddPhotoAlternateRounded /> //it's a mui icon
    </Fab>
  </label>
```